# Dirac delta function integral over given limits

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I know that $\int$$λδ(x-a)=1.λ$ with the limits $$-inf$$ to $$+inf$$ but what if the limits are $$a-ε$$ to $$a+ε$$??
I am guessing it's the same as the former limits but still not sure

Can someone add a homework tag?

Comment: If you understand the Dirac $\delta$-function as a function which is $0$ everywhere, $\infty$ at 0 and integrates to one, then it's really hard to give any help as to how to prove its integral behaviour anywhere (such a function doesn't exist, so proving anything about it is sort of vacuous). If you know a bit of measure theory, and $\delta_{a}$ is Dirac mass at $a,$ then $\int_{a-\varepsilon}^{a+\varepsilon} f\textrm{d} \delta_a=f(a)$ for any function $f$ and any $\varepsilon>0$ is trivial.

Comment: I guess there is a good and natural definition saying that $\int_s^t f(x)\delta(x-a) \textrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_s^t \frac{n}{2} 1_{[-1/n,1/n]}(x-a) f(x)\textrm{d}x,$ where $1_A$ is the indicator function of $A$, at least when $f$ is continuous.  This definition should be able to prove what you want.

Comment: Soooo..... It's not the same answer with both the limits? I just thought that geometrically...

Comment: $\int_s^t f(x)\delta(x-a)\textrm{d}x$ should be $f(a)$ if $a\in [s,t]$ and $0$ else. So yes, the answer is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Heaviside function $H(x)$ is defined as

$$H(x)=
  \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{for $x < 0$} \\
                                   1 & \text{for $x$ > 0} 
  \end{cases}$$

The derivative of the Heaviside function is zero for $x \neq 0$. At $x = 0$ the derivative is undefined. We can represent the derivative of the Heaviside function by the Dirac delta function, $\delta(x)$. The delta function is zero for $x \neq 0$ and infinite at the point $x = 0$. Since the derivative of $H(x)$ is undefined, $\delta(x)$ is not a function in the conventional sense of the word. Heuristically, the delta function is defined by the properties

$$\delta(x)=
  \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{for $x \neq 0$} \\
                                   \infty& \text{for $x = 0$} 
  \end{cases}$$

and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx =1$$

since $\delta(x)$ represents the derivative of $H(x)$. Physically, this function looks like a bump at the origin where the height of the bump becomes arbitrarily large.

[image]

In terms of your homework problem, you have that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-a)dx =1$$

so the above bump is shifted from $x=0$ to $x=a$ (I'm not sure why you include $\lambda$). From the picture above, it is clear that for some small $\epsilon > 0$

$$\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\delta(x)dx =1$$

So, you should calculate

$$\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}\delta(x-a)dx$$

and reach the same conclusion by drawing a similar picture. This approach is entirely heuristic and can be made rigorous through the use of measure theory and the theory of distributions.

Comment: Thank you everyone!!